# Passing state through navigation parameter react native

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, navigation

Ive got the state: const [isPressed, setIsPressed] = useState(false)
Then I want to pass the setIsPressed when navigating to another sreen, which i wrote:
On the from Screen:
onPress{() => navigation.navigate('Map', {setIsPressed})}
On the to Screen:
onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('DM'); setIsPressed(true);}}

However, I get an error saying 'setIsPressed is not a function' when pressing on the To Screen button

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the way you can do it, here is you first screen:

```
const togglePressed = () => setIsPressed(prev=>!prev);



onPress={() =>
   navigation.navigate('ScreenName', {
     onRefreshParent: () => togglePressed(),
   })
}
```

And in you other screen use it like this:

```
 onPress={() => route.params.onRefreshParent && route.params.onRefreshParent()}
```

Comment: In your question you are asking for passing state, but you are actually trying to pass function to change that state. This is the way to do it.